# Trick to getting commodities price history in Quantmod R?

Tags: r, time-series, quantmod, commodity

```
require("quantmod")
```

This works:

```
#Symbol for Natural Gas in front month with Yahoo Finance
getQuote("NGH16.NYM", src="yahoo")
```

but this doesn't"

```
getSymbols("NGH16.NYM", src="yahoo", from="2015-09-01")

    Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,
  cannot open URL 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=NGF16.NYM&a=8&b=01&c=2015&d=11&e=24&f=2015&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=NGF16.NYM&x=.csv'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

How do I get price history?

Comment: What about it doesn't work? What is the output from running `getSymbols("NGH16.NYM", src= "yahoo", from = "2015-09-01")`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You assume that because you can get *current* data snapshots you can also get *historical* series.

That assumption is incorrect.  Data is now an important product for many exchanges, and you generally need to pay for it.

There are other ways, though, and for commodities data [Quandl](http://quandl.com) may be your best bet. Searching for 'natural gas nymex' leads you eg [to this NG_H2014 contract](https://www.quandl.com/data/CME/NGH2014-Natural-Gas-Futures-March-2014-NGH2014-NYMEX), and the [Quandl package on CRAN](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/Quandl/index.html) is excellent because all this is now very scriptable too.

Here eg is the March 2016 expiry from your question:

```
R> str(res <- Quandl("CME/NGH2016"))
'data.frame':   1935 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Date         : Date, format: "2015-12-23" "2015-12-22" "2015-12-21" "2015-12-18" ...
 $ Open         : num  2.05 2.07 2.02 1.97 1.99 ...
 $ High         : num  2.12 2.08 2.09 2.01 2.02 ...
 $ Low          : num  2.01 2.02 1.97 1.91 1.96 ...
 $ Last         : num  2.11 2.05 2.08 1.96 1.96 ...
 $ Change       : num  0.067 0.031 0.093 NA 0.024 0.002 0.068 0.089 0.022 0.033 ...
 $ Settle       : num  2.1 2.03 2.06 1.97 1.97 ...
 $ Volume       : num  37213 32346 59892 53955 80027 ...
 $ Open Interest: num  210758 209803 208883 207250 212823 ...
 - attr(*, "freq")= chr "daily"
R>
```

Or as a zoo object ready for plotting:

```
R> res <- Quandl("CME/NGH2016", type="zoo")
R> plot(res[,"Settle"], main="NGH2016", ylab="Settle")
```

[image]